# Could not find System.Core,version 5.0.5.0 assembly in GAC after installation of Silverlight 5 tool kit for VS2010 with SP1?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I am new to Silverlight.I have installed silverlight 5 tool kit,after installing VS2010

SP1.After Silverlight 5 installation I could not find any Silverlight 5 Dlls i.e

System.Core,version 5.0.5.0  in GAC (Path: c:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL which has only one

System.Core and its version is 3.5.0.0). But I have all the dlls in "C:\Program Files

(x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\silverlight5\" .If I try to put the

System.Core,version 5.0.5.0 manually I wont.Due to this problem I couldn't play with

Silverlight projects.

Comment: Siverlight doesn't use the GAC.

Comment: I have added reference system.core ,version 5.0.5.0 from "C:\Program Files

(x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\silverlight\v5.0".But I could not compile the silverlight project.The compilation error is "Cannot resolve reference assemblies. Please check the reference assemblies. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: Well, hard to explain.  System.Core is already automatically added to any Silverlight project.  Make sure that a "hello world" do-nothing project compiles before you try to use the toolkit.

Comment: Uninstall everything you have related to Silverlight, including the folders. Then install only the latest version. Visual Studio look for past references for some reason. You have to get rid of everything and then install again.

Comment: Hi Vinicius,I have tried what you posted but that didn't get work,still I am getting same error